# Why doesn't Inno Setup constant {userdesktop} work in OutputDir directive and how to fix it?

Tags: inno-setup

I created Inno Setup script, which works perfectly, but I wanted to change `OutputDir` to create the output file on my desktop. But instead of creating output file on desktop it was creating subfolder `{userdesktop}` at the same directory, where script is and output was inside.

I found solution so far, but I believe there should be better way. What am I missing?

```
; these attempts didn't work
[Setup]
OutputDir={userdesktop}
; some more attampts:
OutputDir=userdesktop
OutputDir=userdesktop:
OutputDir="{userdesktop}"

; this workaround worked for me
[Setup]
OutputDir=userdocs:..\Desktop
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Constants](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=consts) like `{userdesktop}` are resolved on install time (on the target user's machine), not on compile time (on your development machine). So it makes no sense to use constants in compile-time only directive like [`OutputDir`](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=setup_outputdir). And actually it's not possible to use them at all (as it's useless).

---

With the default user profile directory layout, use you can use the `userdocs:` prefix, as you did:

```
[Setup]
OutputDir=userdocs:..\Desktop
```

Though it's not a perfect solution, as the *"Documents"* folder can be moved by the user and then the `userdocs:..\Desktop` will not point to the desktop.

---

A more reliable solution is to use [`USERPROFILE` environment variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/deployment/usmt/usmt-recognized-environment-variables) using [`GetEnv` preprocessor function](https://jrsoftware.org/ispphelp/index.php?topic=getenv):

```
[Setup]
OutputDir={#GetEnv('USERPROFILE')}\Desktop
```

Comment: Thanks, last one worked for me, so I left that code. )